# Valgrind error differ in operating systems

Tags: c++, linux, macos, debugging, valgrind

I use valgrind to debug my application. I have two machines where I want to run the code without errors.
One is an ubuntu 11.10 with valgrind 3.7.0 running and one is a Mac OS X 10.7.2 with valgrind 3.6.0 and valgrind 3.8.0.

I run the following valgrind command:

```
 valgrind --track-origins=yes ./my_program
```

On the Linux machine I did not get any error reports. On the Mac valgrind complains about

```
==35723== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==35723==    at 0x10004DCAF: boost::spirit ...
```

As the error is reported in a boost lib I do not think that there might be an error in the boost libraries (boost version is the same on both machines 1.46.1).

What can be the cause for the different error reports?

Comment: The current Boost version is 1.47, how can you have 3.6.1?

Comment: Why do you care about how they can be different? Rather, fix the problem that the one version indicates, then both will pass.

Comment: 3.6.1 is the current version of Valgrind, @tune2fs please fix your question.

Comment: Sorry I have changed the version to 1.46.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Valgrind is not a static analysis tools, but rather a runtime one, i.e. valgrind runs the program on a virtual machine. There is plenty of code in many applications that is not triggered by or compiled for every machine alike, explaining the differences.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using different compilers on the two computers? Perhaps different compilers, or different compiler versions, produce code with different behaviour when accessing an uninitialised variable.

Comment: They are two different versions of gcc on both machines, I try to compile it with the same version.

Answer (score 1):

I've had statements of the form

```
if (A && B) {
  do_stuff
}
```

in which `B` was only initialized if `A` was true.  When I didn't use optimizations, the program (as expected) first checked `A` and then, if it were true, checked `B`.  When optimizing, the compiler found it profitable to check `B` first; *since neither `A` nor `B` had any side effects or depended on volatile memory* this was equivalent.  This latter behavior caused `valgrind` to give me the type of warning you're seeing even though there wasn't anything really wrong with the code.  My guess is that something similar is going on here.